# Nginx is not passing Authentication to gunicorn socket

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, proxy, gunicorn

So I've basically set up my basic backend. Locally the api runs like butter but whenever I deploy the application to production, the API responds always with:
`"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

I think nginx is not passing the header correctly to my socket running gunicorn. But I don't know how I would pass the Header to the socket.

The Authorization is a basic JWT Token, so:
`AUthorization: Bearer bla-blubb-i-am-a-token-420-69`

This is my nginx setup:

```
server {
      listen 80;
    
      server_name dev.website.com;
    
      location = /favicon.ico {
             access_log off; log_not_found off;
      }
    
      location /static {
             alias /home/ubuntu/platform/backend/static;
      }
    
      auth_basic "Admin Login";
    
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    
      location / {
              include proxy_params;
              proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
      }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add `proxy_pass_request_headers on`

Comment: tried that already, did not work...